# Classify matrix representations of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

For a permutation group representation $G \hookrightarrow S_n$ we can classifiy all of them by looking at the translations on some subgroup (which are then the point stabilizers). Is there a similar way to classify all linear representations $G \hookrightarrow GL(V)$ for some vector space $V$ (or similar all matrix representations $G \hookrightarrow M_{n\times n}$)?

Comment: When you say "looking at the translations on some subgroup (which are then the point stabilizers)", are you talking about the fact that every orbit is isomorphic (as a $G$-set) to $G/H$ for some $H$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, thats what I mean.

Comment: You should pick a book on representations of finite groups and read it. The first chapters of the book by Serre, or those of the book by Harris and Fulton. The answer to your question is yes and long.

Comment: All finite groups embed into $S_n$ for some $n$ and all groups embed into ${\rm GL}(V)$ for for some vector space $V$, so you seem to be asking for a classification of the linear representations of all groups.

Comment: For a finite group $G$, all of the linear representations $G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over the complex numbers is well-known, and you can find this in any book on representation theory of finite groups.

Comment: I meant more for a fixed group, in what ways can we embed into into some $GL(V)$, just like we know exactly in what ways we can embed it into $S_n$ by looking at the action on some subgroup. To complicated question?

Comment: @Joppy You cannot seriously be claiming that all linear representations of all finite groups are well-known. That statement immediately implies that all finite groups are well-known.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I misspoke. I meant that the general theory is well-known, and provides useful results: if you know everything there is to know about conjugacy classes in the group, then you can basically do linear algebra to extract a character table and classify all of the irreducible representations. Of course, this is still a hard problem...

Comment: I am still very unsure exactly what the question is here. Also, actions on cosets of subgroups only tell you the homomorphisms of $G$ onto transitive subgroups of $S_n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, by looking at the cosets you know all embeddings into $S_4$, for a given fixed group, at what do I have to look to classifiy all embeddings of this specific group into $GL(V)$ for some $V$?